# Hide certain acf fields wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields, hidden-field

Help

Code in template:

```html
 <?php 
        $groupID = '';
        $fields = get_fields($groupID);

          $fields = get_field_objects();

          if( $fields )
          {
            foreach( $fields as $field_name => $field )
            {
              if( $field['value'] )
              {
                  echo '<ul>';
      echo '<li>' . $field['label'] . ':&nbsp;<strong>' . $field['value'] . '</strong></li>';
                  echo '</ul>';
                }
            }
          }
    

   ?>
```

I need to hide the fields:
  field_5c0a8d44cf56e
  field_5c0a8d4ecf56f
How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not much clear for me, and from my knowledge what I have understood,

for an [acf group](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/group/) you don't want to loop through, the control is yours,
so you can print it straightaway

but if you really want to do it in a loop then,

```
if( $fields )
      {
        foreach( $fields as $field_name => $value )
        {
          if( $value && !in_array($field_name, ["field_5c0a8d44cf56e", "field_5c0a8d4ecf56f"])
          {
              echo '<ul>';
                 echo '<li>' . $field_name . ':&nbsp;<strong>' . $value . '</strong></li>';
              echo '</ul>';
            }
        }
      }
```

Comment: You helped. Thanks a lot!